# javafx 8 fxml negation

Tags: javafx, fxml, negation

Using FXML with JavaFx 8.

I have few ToggleButtons in toggleGroup, defined as:

```
<ToggleGroup fx:id="operater" />
```

I want to disable OK button, when no operater is selected. Actually, I want to negate the disable expression in ok button:

```
<Button disable="${operater.selectedToggle.selected}" fx:id="ok" text="OK" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#okClick"  >
```

I have tried with ! and with not(), but no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [expression binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding):

```
disable="${!operater.selectedToggle.selected}"
```

operater is spelt operator.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work for me. Intellij shows red-highlighted error and FXML construction throws NPE.

Comment: It is possible that Intellij doesn't correctly parse the expressions in FXML (not sure I haven't tried that), but regardless the expressions should work when the FXML is loaded in Java.  Not sure why you get the NPE though.